# SQL Server upgrade from 2008 R2 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This morning I had a discussion with my boss about the SQL Server upgrade from 2008 R2 to 2012.

I was explaining to him that we can detach or do a backup from SQL Server 2008, and then re-attach or restore the data in SQL Server 2012. Then, he asked me 3 questions in which I have absolutely no idea (what he was asking)?

1. How do you upgrade the Database Engine?
2. How do you upgrade the SQL Server Reporting Service?
3. Can you run both SQL Server 2008 and 2012 side by side?

My assumption was that once you upgrade or install the new instance SQL Server 2012, everything else should be taken care of, or am I wrong?

Comment: Might I suggest that this would be a better question for http://serverfault.com?

Comment: 1 - You install the upgrade. 2 - see #1. 3 - Yes, this is called named instances and you absolutely can run both on the same server.

Comment: Word of caution... I had an issue attaching a 2008 db to a new 2012 server, but not consistently. I've not been able to find a pattern.